# Awk to generate a file of 100 lines using 5 lines supplied based on some condition

Tags: copy, increment, paste

I have a file with 5 lines in it. I'd like to copy and paste these lines until a condition is satisfied.. e.g.,

```
     123 89.98 34.56
     AbcDef
     0.0  10.567
     Hijkl
     XYZ 345
```

I'd like to repeat these lines 20 times and each time incrementing the number '123' (on the fist line) by 1. i.e.,

```
     123 89.98 34.56
     AbcDef
     0.0  10.567
     Hijkl
     XYZ 345
     124 89.98 34.56
     AbcDef
     0.0  10.567
     Hijkl
     XYZ 345
     .....
     .....
     172 89.98 34.56
     AbcDef
     0.0  10.567
     Hijkl
     XYZ 345
```

Is this possible?

Comment: A "for next" or "do while" loop seems logical but were do you want to use it? which developer environment do you use?

Comment: This is just an ascii input file read by an engineering software, which can only read in this format.

Comment: Sorry, but without any developer tools it will be very hard to do. You might concider Excel.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it (but without any elegance) is this:

1) Get a file with the desired final number of lines (in your case, 20x5). Let's name it "100lines.txt".

2) Do:

> awk '{if(NR%5==1) {print (NR+4)/5+122, "89.98 34.56"} if(NR%5==2) {print "AbcDef"} if(NR%5==3) {print "0.0  10.567"} if(NR%5==4) {print "Hijkl"} if(NR%5==0) {print "XYZ 345"}}' 100lines.txt

I think it could work.